# Macro vs. Static functions in Header

Tags: c

for a lot of quick tasks where one could employ a function `f(x,y)`, in plain C, macros are used. I would like to ask specifically about these cases, that are solvable by a function call (i.e. macros used for inlining functions, not for code expansion of arbitrary code).

Typically C functions are not inlined since they might be linked to from other C files. However, static C functions are only visible from within the C file they are defined in. Therefore they can be inlined by compilers. I have heard that a lot of macros should be replaced by turning them into static functions, because this produces safer code.

Are there cases where this is a not good idea?

Again: Not asking about Code-Production macros with ## alike constructs that cannot at all be expressed as a function.

Comment: I think your question might have been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104568/macro-vs-function-in-c and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358232/why-use-macros-in-c

Comment: writing a proper macro is a pain, and `inline`ing functions just ensures it can be defined multiple times in the binary, the compiler can decide whether it will actually inline it to maybe save space

Comment: I would actually suspect most of these are historical reasons. Ages ago, the C compilers didn't inline functions at all. So people used macros for things they wanted inlined. C code is usually unusually long-lived.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: C does not have `inline`, this is not about C++.

Comment: @wirrbel Of course there is `inline` in C, at least since C99. For a quick overview, see [Wikipedia on inline functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function#Comparison_with_macros).

Comment: @amon: oh, my bad. I have to stick to C90 though :(

Comment: C99 `inline` is different from C++ `inline`.  You have to explicitly instantiate an inline function once and only once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Macros  that are solvable by a function call have a lot of pitfalls:

- They are hard to write, because you may have to handle properly arguments like `++i`.
- They are hard to debug with a visual debugger since you cannot step through a macro
  or put a breakpoint there.
- They are hard to handle correctly when analysing compilations dependencies.

Macros that are solvable by a function call could have been useful to provide inlining in a primitive compiler.  I am not aware of any compiler not handling inline functions and some can even inline across compilation units.

> Typically C functions are not inlined since they might be linked to from other C files.

There is no reason why a compiler would not be able to provide two versions of a function, a traditional `call`ed one and an `inline`d one.  You should look at the documentation of the compiler you are targetting.  Also, you may want to look at generated assembly: even if you do not know assembly, you can quickly learn to tell if some function has been inlined or not. (Start with baby-examples to quickly learn this.)